# jquery: get parent element from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

How to make this code work? I don't see how I can reach `div` from within `$.get` callback.

```
$("<div/>", {
    text: "some text",
    click: function (e) {
        $.get("bar.php", function(data) {
             $(this).text(data); // doesn't work
    });
    }
}).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a variable inside the click handler that holds the reference to the DIV and use that variable inside the $.get callback.

```
$("<div/>", {
    text: "some text",
    click: function (e) {
        var $div = $(this);
        $.get("bar.php", function(data) {
             $div.text(data); // should work
    });
    }
}).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Found a simple explanation here https://www.codehaven.co.uk/jquery/jquery-ajax/refer-to-parent-element-from-within-ajax-call-jquery/ which is the same example.